# Is there a way to count the number of observations in a column of a data frame and save that as a character string?

Tags: r

I am working on graphics for a project and would like to add the number of observations at the bottom of the graph. I accomplished this using code
`table(dat$year)`
which returns

```
2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 
  41   83   34   56   43   22
```

However, I realized that for one of my columns I have a sizable amount of NA entries so instead of just the number of observations in that year, I need to find the number of observations in that column broken up by year and excluding NA results. Basically what I need is Excel's "count" function broken up by year.

Internet searching has only lead me to find how to get the frequency of each observation in the column (I realize this is what the `table()` function does) and while that was fine before I realized my mistake, obviously that wont work now.

Using some small example data,

```
dat
year  a  b  c
2014  1  1  NA
2014  1  2  NA
2014  2  2  3
2015  NA 3  3 
2015  1  2  NA
2015  1  1  1
2016  2  1  1
2016  1  3  1
2016  1  2  NA
```

This problem is the opposite of problems described here, [Create frequency tables for multiple factor columns in R] ([Create frequency tables for multiple factor columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291674/create-frequency-tables-for-multiple-factor-columns-in-r)) and here, [Counting frequencies of each letter for multiple column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044060/counting-frequencies-of-each-letter-for-multiple-column). Whereas these two posts would result in tables like this:

```
      1  2  3
2014  3  3  1
2015  4  1  2
2016  4  2  3
```

My ideal result would return something similar to

```
  2014  2015  2016
a    3     2     3    
b    3     3     3 
c    1     2     2
```

that I could then use as a character string for an x axis label.

EDIT:
My problem has been solved below.

Comment: Try with `table(dat$year[col(dat[-1])], unlist(dat[-1]))`

Comment: @akrun that function simply creates a table that has the frequency of every number in the data frame.

Comment: Pretty similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48044060/5325862)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  We `gather` the columns 'a' to 'c' to 'long' format, get the frequency count with `count` and `spread`to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
  gather(key, val, a:c, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  count(year, key) %>% 
  spread(year, n)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  key   `2014` `2015` `2016`
#  <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 a          3      2      3
#2 b          3      3      3
#3 c          1      2      2
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(year = c(2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L), a = c(1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L
), b = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), c = c(NA, NA, 3L, 
3L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful and will go a long way in solving my problem.